# How can i read each row till the first occurence of NaN.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

**From excel file i want to read each row and use it independently to process**

*here how the data looks like in excel file*

12  32  45  67  89  54  23  56  78  98
34  76  34  89  34  3
76  34  54  12  43  78  56
76  56  45  23  43  45  67  76  67  8
87  9   9   0   89  90  6   89
23  90  90  32  23  34  56  9   56  87
23  56  34  3   5   8   7   6   98
32  23  34  6   65  78  67  87  89  87
12  23  34  32  43  67  45
343 76  56  7   8   9   4

but when i read it through pandas then the remaining columns are filled with NaN.

*the data after reading from pandas looks like*

> 0 12  32  45  67  89  54  23.0    56.0    78.0    98.0
>
> 1 34  76  34  89  34  3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
>
> 2 76  34  54  12  43  78  56.0    NaN NaN NaN
>
> 3 76  56  45  23  43  45  67.0    76.0    67.0    8.0
>
> 4 87  9   9   0   89  90  6.0 89.0    NaN NaN
>
> 5 23  90  90  32  23  34  56.0    9.0 56.0    87.0
>
> 6 23  56  34  3   5   8   7.0 6.0 98.0    NaN
>
> 7 32  23  34  6   65  78  67.0    87.0    89.0    87.0
>
> 8 12  23  34  32  43  67  45.0    NaN NaN NaN
>
> 9 343 76  56  7   8   9   4.0 5.0 8.0 68.0

Here it can be seen the remaining columns of each row is filled with NaN which i don't want.
Nor i wanted to replace it with some other value or drop the whole rows contains NaN .

**How can i read columns of each row till the first occurence of NaN. ?**

> For eg.The second row in pandas is 34 76  34  89  34  3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
>
> so my desired output will be that it reads only 34    76  34  89  34  3

**My preference is pandas but if not possible then is their any other way of doing it like with some other libraries**
Any resource or reference will be helpful?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While calling the pd.read_excel function, try setting keep_default_na = False. This will avoid default NaN values while reading.

Comment: It worked thanks...but when i m passing it through ar model it gives me an error "can't convert string to float"